# Reference tunnel variable within a "%>%" chain

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Following up from my prior question - how can you reference the newly created column later in the analysis? How can you reference `.data[["cyl"]]` and rename the title as `cyl`?

[Tunnel data-variables through env-variable with "{{" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305159/tunnel-data-variables-through-env-variable-with-operator)

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.2
# Variables to pass into function
params <-  setdiff(colnames(mtcars) ,"mpg") %>% head(3)

graph_by <- function(data, by, var, prefix = "avg") {
  data %>%
    group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    summarise(mean_value := mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(mean_value, {{ by }})) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() 
}

graph_by(mtcars, by = cyl, var = mpg)
```

[image]

```r
purrr::map(params, ~ graph_by(mtcars, by = .data[[.x]], var = mpg))
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

```r
## Goal would be to refer to the created variable later in the analysis

# graph_by <- function(data, by, var, prefix = "avg") {
#   data %>%
#     group_by({{ by }}) %>%
#     summarise("{prefix}_{{ var }}" := mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
#     ggplot(aes(.data[[.x]], {{ by }})) +
#     geom_line() +
#     geom_point() +
#     labs(x = "{{ by }}")
# }
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a bug in ggplot2, can you file an issue and tag me in it please (my github handle is `@lionel-`).

Comment: Is the issue that you are trying to keep the function able to take both bare variable names as well as strings for the same argument?  When I make a function with arguments that will take strings I put the `.data[[by]]` inside the function and then pass strings to `by`.  That way I can add, e.g.,  `labs(x = by)` to the plotting code to get useful axis names.

Comment: @LionelHenry - did the solution by MrFlick solve the issue? Do you still need a github issue filed?

Comment: yes it's a bug, it should be properly labelled with `.data[[`. MrFlick's solution changes the interface of your function (takes symbols instead of expressions) and is a little less safe because of ensym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version will work

```
graph_by <- function(data, by, var, prefix = "avg") {
  by <- rlang::ensym(by)  
  data %>%
    group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    summarise(mean_value := mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(mean_value, {{by}})) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() 
}

purrr::map(params, ~ graph_by(mtcars, by = !!.x, var = mpg))
```

Note that we do the expansion in the `map` call with `!!` and then use `ensym` explicitly so it will accept both literal character values and unquoted symbols.